# Does SelectBuilder prevents sparql injection?

Tags: jena

We are trying to prevent the sparql injection attacks in our application.To generate sparql queries we have used apache jean query builder classes(org.apache.jena.arq.querybuilder).
Is it enough to prevent the injection attacks?

We have tried by injecting the multiple triples instead of literal, query does not return any data. So does it mean query builder classes prevent injection?

```
String username="admin\". ?subject ?p ?o . ?subject <urn:publicid:property;name> \"admin";

SelectBuilder sb = new SelectBuilder().addVar( "*" ).addWhere( "?s", RDF.type, Namespace.USER_META_TYPE )
                .addWhere( "?s", Namespace.USER_NAME, username );
```

I expect the resultset should be empty same thing has happened.

Answer (score 1):

The addWhere( s, p, o ) method checks each object (s, p, or o) for type.  In the case of strings it calls the `org.apache.jena.sparql.util.NodeFactoryExtra` method `public static Node parseNode(String nodeString, PrefixMap pmap)`  method.  This means that strings that

- start with '<' and and with '> are converted to URIs.
- start with "_:" are converted to anonymous nodes.
- start with " or '' are strings
- start with "?" are converted to variable type nodes.
- contain only digits and '.' are converted to numeric literal node types.
- are of the form prefix:localName where prefix is in the prefix map and localName is a valid localName are converted to URIs.
- All other values are returned as strings.

This means that there is not a risk of injection in either QueryBuilder or UpdateBuilders.